# Where to put a file in Laravel not available to the public

Tags: laravel

I'd like to put a simple txt file (with spam email domains) in a place that's not in the `/public` folder. If I put a file or folder in `/storage` then it gets ignored and I can't push it to my repo and deploy it, so I was wondering where to put it.

Comment: The `resources` folder? Or create a new folder? Why does it get ignored in the `storage` folder? Only `storage/*.key` files seem to be ignored

Comment: Don't know why it gets ignored. In the resources folder the app can directly access a file with `file(url('/resources/file.txt'))`?

Comment: Laravel has a [resource_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-resource-path) helper. Did you check your `.gitignore` files why it might get ignored in `storage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it in your `/storage` folder you can add the file name to the `.gitignore` file in the same folder. Then it gets commited to your repo too.

Let's say you put it in `/storage/app/public`. Then you open `/storage/app/public/.gitignore` and add `spam_email_domains.txt` to it.

If you already have entries in `.gitignore` with a `*` wildcard which tells git to ignore everything then you need to put `!spam_email_domains.txt` in the `.gitignore` file to exclude it from `*` wildcard:

```
*
!logo.jpg
!spam_email_domains.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put it in the `config` folder as a config file, the `storage` folder sounds like the best place for me. Maybe make a subfolder like `spam` or something, so you can put additional files like this in it.

You can use path helpers, to get the absolut path:

```
$path = storage_path('spam/file.txt');
```

Also take a look into your .gitignore file in the project root. This file determines which folders and files are ignored. On a fresh laravel installation only `/storage/*.key` should be ignored.

Comment: "_If I put a file or folder in `/storage` then it gets ignored and I can't push it to my repo_"

Comment: thanks, forgot to mention that part. updated my answer. unusual, but solvable.